# Search for answers of some user to questions in my favorites

Tags: support, answers, search, bookmarks

On [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com) I searched for

```
 infavorites:73067  user:dddd
```

where `dddd` is the numerical user ID of some user, and got one result. It is the one **question** by the user that I marked as a favorite. But I have several/many questions marked as favorites because of **answers** by that user. These are not shown.

Is there a way to search for answers by a given user to the questions I have marked as a favorite?

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: I would like to reduce the number of favorites to skim for an answer that I am interested in. Since we cannot, to my knowledge, mark answers as favorite, I have to mark the questions. But they are often irrelevant to me. I only remember the answer and its author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with the regular search functionality, but this sounds like a job for the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

[This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/1168041/search-for-answers-of-a-specific-user-to-questions-in-my-favorites?AnotherUserId=77072&UserId=73067) should work; it accepts two parameters, one of which is your own user ID and another the ID of the user whose answers you're searching for. It shows you didn't favorite one of the only two questions I've ever answered on Physics Stack Exchange, which was expected.

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning. If you're interested in how it works, please take the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).